# Error 64 at YAML parse (R Markdown to PPT)

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown

I am trying to create a powerpoint using R Markdown. Every time I tried to knit, this error always appears:

```
YAML parse exception at line 4, column 0,
while scanning for the next token:
found character that cannot start any token
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 64
Execution halted
```

Below are the first 6 lines of my .rmd file. (I only put the numbers for clarity of which lines are what number)

```
1 ---
2 title: "PPT Final"
3 author: "Anonymous"
4 date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
5 output: powerpoint_presentation
6 ---
```

I have tried running my code at other types of files that can be produced from R Markdown like HTML, word, etc. It shows the same error message. How do I fix this?

Comment: Your YAML works fine in my environment. You may need to provide the version number of relevant packages (run `rmarkdown::pandoc_version(); packageVersion("knitr"); packageVersion("rmarkdown")` and show the results), or you may need to show all lines in YAML senction, so that others can tell where is the cause of the error. Also, you have to check whether the all indentations in the YAML section is valid (i.e. verify whether there are only even numbers of spaces [two or four spaces for instance] for any indentation).